# How do I round 4.3 to 4.5

Tags: php

Given a value that has 1 decimal place, how do I round that decimal place up a half step?

If I have a value of, say, `4.3`, how do I round that in PHP to `4.5`?

Other examples would be:

```
3.8 >> 4.0
2.1 >> 2.5
0.9 >> 1.0
```

Also I should mention that I am running PHP version 5.2.17

Thanks!

Comment: Note, you didn't include any `2.6`-style numbers, where the number will round to the closest value (see the [demo](http://codepad.org/KVKFGMuv) for @icktoofay's answer). If you want them to round up, that would be a more specific answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<?php
    $value=10000.1;
    echo ceil($value*2)/2 . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: @deceze - That's correct; I was wondering if that was a typo or not, hence my comment below the question. But at least with the example numbers in the question, it appears that a round up is what the OP is after.

Comment: Precisely, thank you. This is exactly what I was going for. Nice catch deceze.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.

```
ceil($num * 2) / 2
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Will mark as answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

an example is:

```
<?php echo round(8.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); ?> // result 9
```

Comment: Tried this before I posted the question and it didn't work, and I wondered if it was due to my PHP version (which I updated the question with). icktoofay's answer worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe the OP would want the answer to be 8.5 here... rounding to nearest half step. It doesn't appear PHP has mode for round that accomplishes what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test atm but if the other answers don't work this should round to the nearest .5

```
function toNearestHalf($float) {
    $int = (int) $float;
    $half = $int + 0.5;

    return $float < $half ? $half : ($int + 1);
}
```