# Calculate average from array with fmod()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a rating array in which there is a list of ratings of a particular product from where I want the result to be average rating.

What I want to achieve is if average rating is `4.2 or 4.3` or something in between `4 to 4.5` it should result as 4.5 and if average rating is like 4.6 or 4.7 or something it should result as 5 rating.

I have done stuff which is resulting 4.5 still if average rating os 4.2 or 4.6.

```
$product_ratings = Array
                  (
                     [0] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                     [1] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                     [2] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 3.5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                     [3] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                     [4] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 2.5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                     [5] => stdClass Object
                     (
                        [id] => 93
                        [product_id] => 5
                        [rating] => 4.5
                        [user_id] => 154
                     )
                   )
                $r = 0;
                $rating_total="";
                foreach ($product_ratings as $row) {
                    $rating_total += $row->rating;
                    $r++;
                }
                $average_rating = "";     
                if($rating_total != "" || $rating_total != 0)
                {
                    $average_rating = $rating_total / $r;
                }
                else
                {
                    $average_rating = 0;
                }
                $avg_rating = $average_rating - fmod($average_rating, 0.5);
                echo $avg_rating
```

Comment: Have your tried using the `round` function in php? http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: yes but what i want to achieve is not possible with `round`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365172/how-do-i-round-4-3-to-4-5

Comment: It solved the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I round 4.3 to 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365172/how-do-i-round-4-3-to-4-5)